# How do I style individual pages in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, routes, navbar

I am trying to style individual pages in React Typescript, but when I click on a new Nav link the home/root page is on all the other pages. How do I remove the same page from these other links so that I can style them individually?

/*This is the main page*/

```
`import "./App.css";
import Navbar from "./Components/Navbar";
import Container from "./Components/Container";

import Home from "./pages/Home";
import About from "./pages/About";
import Contact from "./pages/Contact";
import Experience from "./pages/Experience";

function App() {
  let Component;
  switch (window.location.pathname) {
    case "/App":
      Component = <Home />;
      break;
    case "/About":
      Component = <About />;
      break;
    case "/Contact":
      Component = <Contact />;
      break;
    case "/Experience":
      Component = <Experience />;
      break;
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      {Component}
      <Container />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;`



/*This is the NavBar*/

`export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <>
      <nav className="nav">
        <h1 className="logo">. ALEX -- .</h1>
        <p>Software Engineer/Web Developer</p>
        <ul>
          <li className="nav-items">
            <a href="/Home">Home</a>
            <a href="/About">About</a>
            <a href="/Experience">Experience</a>
            <a href="/Contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
}
```

`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to add blank pages to my portfolio website so that when a user clicks on a nav link from the home page, they're taken to a completely blank page with no navbar